# Internal Server Error (500) when trying to invoke a Azure Function wrapped in a Docker container

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions

When trying to invoke an Azure Function wrapped in a Docker container all I get is an internal server error 500.

Here is what I did to create my container:

```
mkdir docker-function
cd docker function
func init --docker
func new (I then selected Http Trigger)
docker build -t hello-docker-function:latest .
docker tag hello-docker-function myaccount/hello-docker-function
docker push myaccount/hello-docker-function:latest
```

I then created an Azure Function in US Central, selected Docker (on Linux).
I then clicked `Configure container settings`.
As `Image source` I selected `Docker Hub`
As `Repository Access` I selected `Public`
As `Image` I specified `myaccount/hello-docker-function`
I did not specify any kind of `Startup file`

When invoking the function (via its URL or via the `Run` button) all I get is an internal server error 500.

I also tried with the Azure Container Registry - same result.

Any idea?

Comment: Should you specify "myaccount/hello-docker-function:latest" but not "myaccount/hello-docker-function" in "Image" box ? Missing tag(:latest) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce the problem, and also received a 500 response code.

As it seems the problem was related to 2 things: the authentication which must be either configured or disabled and the worker runtime which must be specified.

So 2 things that made it work for me:

1. Setting the `authLevel` to `anonymous` in `function.json`. 
   If you want to enable the authentication, this question might be helpful: [Http Trigger Azure Function in Docker with non anonymous authLevel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53126627/http-trigger-azure-function-in-docker-with-non-anonymous-authlevel)
2. In the Azure Web UI FunctionApp configuration page set the `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` to `node` (I used nodeJS).

Comment: Thanks, I set the `authLevel` but indeed forgot to specify the `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME`- thanks!